# multithreaded c exe crash but not within vs2013 debug

Tags: c, multithreading, dll

Using Visual Studio 2013 Express, I have developed a multithreaded dll in c, and an associated exe which uses some of the dll functions. Everything works fine as long as I start the exe from within VS IDE (Local Windows Debugger); however, the dll crashes when the exe is run from the command line. By attaching to the running exe from within the IDE, I could see that the crash always happen at the `WaitForMultipleObjects()` call, but that really does not help much, as the stack trace for the spawned threads is lost somewhere inside ntdll.dll .

Below is the dll code snippet where the How can I isolate and fix the problem?
Thanks!

```
for (pr_id=0; pr_id<pBestPredictorsCount; pr_id++){
    arg[FH][pr_id]->OutputType = FH;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->CBaseVal = CRec[0].High;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->PredictorId = pr_id;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->Delta = vDelta;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->Scale = vHpScale;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->DebugLevel = pDebugLevel;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->LogFile = pLogFile;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->TotalBars = pTotalBars;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->PredictionLen = pPredictionLen;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->Forecast = oForecast;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->ChrMutex = ChrMutex;
    arg[FH][pr_id]->CVal = vCVal[FH];
    arg[FH][pr_id]->HVal = vHVal[FH];
    handle[ThreadCount] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)DoGATrainAndRun,
                          (void*)arg[FH][pr_id], 0, &th_id);
    ThreadCount++;

    arg[FL][pr_id]->OutputType = FL;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->CBaseVal = CRec[0].High;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->PredictorId = pr_id;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->Delta = vDelta;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->Scale = vHpScale;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->DebugLevel = pDebugLevel;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->LogFile = pLogFile;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->TotalBars = pTotalBars;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->PredictionLen = pPredictionLen;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->Forecast = oForecast;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->ChrMutex = ChrMutex;
    arg[FL][pr_id]->CVal = vCVal[FL];
    arg[FL][pr_id]->HVal = vHVal[FL];
    handle[ThreadCount] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)DoGATrainAndRun,
                          (void*)arg[FL][pr_id], 0, &th_id);
    ThreadCount++;
}

WaitForMultipleObjects(ThreadCount, handle, TRUE, INFINITE);
for (i = 0; i < ThreadCount; i++)
    CloseHandle(handle[i]);
```

Comment: This is a joke right? You don't seriously think that the code dump is acceptably formatted, right? Hanlon's Razer sure, but there have to be limits.

Comment: This is not an MCVE. It's not even a runnable program. Not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: I don't know if I'm able to help, but someone might if you said what the nature of the "crash" was.  Does it happen in the debug and release builds of when run standalone? Have you tried creating an event logger to trace events leading up to the failure?  (needs some sort of semaphore or mutex, but apply KISS so you're not debugging your debug tools instead of the problem.)

Comment: My apologies for the horrible code formatting;

Comment: About the relevant comments that were posted, this happens in both Debug and Release configurations. What I have tried is to attach VS2013 debugger to the standaloine exe while it's running, and that's how I was able to identify that   the main thread is on WaitForMultipleObjects(), while children threads are somewhere within ntdll.dll. I also inserted a number of printf() within the posted for..loop , and I could see that the crash appears to happen randomly (i.e., sometimes pr_id=0, sometimes up to 3...) ...

Comment: Perhaps you could create a static global struct or array of "state" variables, one for each thread, and insert code in each thread to update (increment probably good enough) it's state variable to show progress in that thread, so you can get an idea of where each thread is when the crash occurs.

Comment: If the symptons move with the environment, it's quite possible there is corruption happening elsewhere, sometimes with benign, sometimes with fatal results. Two avenues of approach are a) examine all your memory allocations, and their indexing, remove casts from the `void*` pointer returned in case they are hiding a compiler warning/error (enable all compiler warnings anyway), b) look out for anything else that isn't working quite as expected, and that might be the culprit.

Comment: Thanks @weather-wane for the suggestion; by using Visual Leak Detector, I was able to find  a number of memory leaks, and I fixed all of them. I also removed the (void*) cast before the arguments array in CreateThread() call. However, the behavior is unchanged: everything works fine when launching the Local Debugger, while it crashes when calling the .exe from the command line... The last thing I want to try before abandoning the whole idea of multithreading is to install VS2010 and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @rcgldr for the suggestion; I tried a slightly simpler approach: I stuck a printf(GetCurrentThreadId()) at the very first line in the called routine (DoGATrainAndRun); what I found is that most of the times the exe crashes **before** getting there, apparently somewhere inside CreateThread() ...

Answer (score -1):

As per my previous comment, I installed MS Visual C++ 2010 Express , re-created the project from scratch, and recompiled it.
This did indeed solve my problem, as my .exe now runs flawlessly.
As I suspected, it's as if the root cause of the crash lies within VS2013 libraries, perhaps MSVCRT120(D).dll, but I'll leave it to someone else to figure that out.

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that the root cause for the problem lies in the libraries. While VS has a reputation for shipping libraries with a high bug count, you should never blindly blame library code over your own code. Unless you can specifically point out a known bug in VS that explains the behavior, it's probably your code that is faulty.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: You may be right in general, but here I'm not doing anything _blindly_ ; on the contrary, I merely pointed out that the very same code runs fine when compiled in VC2010, while crashes when compiled in VS2013. That's as eye-open as it can get...